# Replacing stair risers: three issues

Tags: stairs, carpentry

These stair risers had an unattractive tile on them  so I removed it.

I have three issues I need to address:

1. I need to get the tile residue off. I'm thinking paint stripper will do the job here
2. I need to replace the straight risers. I don't know if I can just paint the wood that's there or if I should cut 1/4" plywood
3. I need to replace/cover the curved riser (*last step curves to the wall, out of picture*). I'm hearing I should put a veneer on with contact adhesive, but there are so many options on Google so I can't figure out what to buy. Is there a specific veneer good for curved risers?

[image: Picture of close-up with glue/mastic?]

[image: Picture including curved riser]

Comment: Can you clarify #2, It seems to make #1 unnecessary.  #3, OK is there a question there?

Comment: If removing the residue and painting would look okay aesthetically then I think you're right that #2 would be unnecessary. If it wouldn't, I think I need to remove the residue so I have a flat surface and then replace with something. I guess the question for #2 is which path would work better. I edited to clarify #3.

Comment: Your stairs functionally work.   So this really is just about whatever you think looks good.   To take off the residue... it is either mastic or glue.   Scrape it off or use a glue solvent - these range from nice to pretty harsh (harsh ones work faster).    What can you put there?   Whatever you want as long as stairs are functional.

Comment: Veneer is typically very thin, It will bend to a curve nicely. Just watch some YouTube videos on veneering. https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=++veneering+wood++on+a+curved+surface  - Actually you could veneer 1/4" plywood and glue it over the old tile thinset and be done with it. NO stripping, scraping etc, and all the risers will match.

Comment: That looks like either drywall or, perhaps, cement board as a backer for the tiles that were there. If that's the case, frankly, it would be _far_ easier to simply break it out, unscrew it, whatever, to completely remove all the riser backing and start from scratch. Then you can install whatever substrate you want and whatever cover you want. You could even just install one single piece of nice wood and finish that directly without _any_ "covering" at all.

Comment: Also, you mention a "curved riser", yet there aren't any curves in your picture. You might want to [edit] to include a picture of this/these riser(s) to give us an idea of what you're dealing with. There are many options for working around a curve, recommended options are based on the curve at hand.

Comment: Good point. I wanted to take another picture yesterday, but unfortunately I wasn't able to get in while our hardwood was being sanded and stained. I edited.  I also ordered two of [these](https://www.homedepot.com/p/PureEdge-24-in-x-96-in-Poplar-Real-Wood-Veneer-with-10-mil-Paperback-903773/312591265) for the curved riser and to match with the others

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Answer (score 0):

My neighbor went to the Lowes or home Depot, I do not know which one, and bought a step renewal kit that consisted of treads and riser covers. He and I installed them on his stairs that ran from the lower to the upper level of his home. The stair kit came in several different finishes. He chose the finish his wife wanted. When completed the steps looked great and his wife was very happy. (You know what that means). They were fairly easy to install. If you are not good with tools ask a neighbor or friend to help. My 2 cents.